# How do I prove this identity for summations?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

How would I go about proving this identity? I really have no idea where to even start, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \left( i + 1 \right) \left( \left( i + 1 \right) ! \right) = \left( n + 2 \right) ! - 1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $(i+1)(i+1)!=(i+2)!-(i+1)!$

Now the sum becomes $$2!-1!+3!-2!+...+(n+1)!-n!+(n+2)!-(n-1)!=(n-2)!-1!=(n-2)!-1$$

Comment: How did you get this?  (i+1)(i+1)!=(i+2)!−(i+1)!  I thought I am supposed to prove that the sum for n+1 = (n+3)!-1 but I'm having trouble getting there

Comment: Okay I actually got it, using your hint. However, can you explain how you came up with that?

Comment: @etnie1031 It's common to use telescope sums with especially factorials. Also, you can use induction and sometimes that also works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using induction by letting $\mathrm P(n)$ be the proposition that $$\sum_{i=0}^n = (i+1)(i+1)! = (n+2)!$$

Your base case $\mathrm P(0)$ is $$(1)(1)!=2!-1$$

Now you just have to prove that $\mathrm P(k)\Rightarrow\mathrm P(k+1)$. Can you go from there?

Comment: Thanks, I get now that I'm supposed to show that P(k+1) = (n+3)!-1. I got to the point where I have ∑i=0n+1 = (n+2)!-1 + (n+2)((n+2)!) . I just can't get that to simplify to (n+3)!-1